# Placement of figures at the end of document

Tags: floats, positioning

I want to place all the figures at the end of the document in nature.cls can some one help me in this

renewenvironmentfigureletcaptionnatfigcaption newcommandnatfigcaption2 atenddocument refstepcounterfigure ifthenelsevaluefigure1 newpagenoindent ruletextwidth1pt sectionfigure legends parvfill sffamily noindenttextbffigure arabicfigurehspace1em#2 renewenvironmenttablefloattablepsffamilyendfloat ignore all includegraphics commands in the document atbegindocumentletincludegraphicsnatignore newcommandnatignore2

Comment: Could you clean up your post and provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)? Also, we would need to know where to get `nature.cls`... Could you provide a link?

Comment: Package `endfloat` might help